# UICollectionView warning

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

Warning:
`The item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.`

Code:

```
extension SaleViewController {
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
        checkEstimatedSize()
    }

    func checkEstimatedSize(){
        if(DeviceType.IS_IPAD || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight){
            if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
                layout.invalidateLayout()
            }
        }else{
            if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
                layout.invalidateLayout()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure where the problem is... it has the `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` and like a `wrap_content` on iPads.
The error sounds like `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`; it works sometimes. When it does, works perfectly. When it doesn't, it freezes and fills the Log as follows:

`The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x10313a9a0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x104096e00; frame = (10 138; 300 420); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c0458750>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c02254e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {300, 220}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x10313a9a0>.
2018-10-04 11:03:35.869371-0500 MyApp[276:5353] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2018-10-04 11:03:35.869398-0500 MyApp[276:5353] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2018-10-04 11:03:35.869445-0500 MyApp[276:5353] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2018-10-04 11:03:35.869555-0500 MyApp[276:5353] Please check the values returned by the delegate.`

And basically, it repeats the same Log over and over again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On emulator works fine ??? So it could be be difference in iOS versions ? It works on some versions and others no ?

Comment: After running plenty tests, seems to have the problem on both. Updating question.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem appears because the reference `width` is bigger then "working" width of your `collectionView`

To fix this you must calculate your cells reference size properly.

You're using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, so you can take an advantage of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement the following method (It is provided for the case when cells has fullscreen `width` and dynamic height):

```
        /// UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                            layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                            sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            var referenceHeight: CGFloat = 54.0 // Approximate height of the cell
            // Cell width calculation
            let sectionInset = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInset
            let referenceWidth = collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width
                - sectionInset.left
                - sectionInset.right
                - collectionView.contentInset.left
                - collectionView.contentInset.right

                return CGSize(width: referenceWidth, height: referenceHeight)
            }
        }
```

Keep in mind, that if you're using multiple columns, you should calculate cells `width` accordingly, and `minInteritemSpacing` should be taken into account. Hope it helps.